# Why are uncountable discrete spaces never separable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to show: $A:=\{(x,-x)\in \Bbb R^2\}$ is, as a Subspace of $(\Bbb R^2, T)$, discrete and therefore not separable.

I've found the argument that since the boundary of $A$ is equal to $A$ (therefore $\bar A = A$), and A is not countable, there can't be a countable subspace $B$ with $\bar B=A$ which is the requirement for $A$ beeing separable.

I don't really understand how $\bar A = A$ leads to there not beeing a subspace which fulfills $\bar B=A$. What about $B:=\{(x,-x)\in \Bbb Q^2\}$ ? Wouldn't this fulfill the requirements since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q^2$ is countable ?

(I think it has something to do with A beeing a subspace of $(\Bbb R^2, T)$)

Also what is meant by A beeing discrete? I know that the discrete topology is the one induced by the power set, but is that really what is meant here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What topology is $T$? Under the usual topology, the subset $A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, hence non discrete and separable.

Comment: @egreg the topology of the product of the Sorgenfrey line, it must be.

Comment: As stated in the answer: In the discrete topology on S, every subset of S is open (and also closed).It is also called the fine,or finest, topology on S. The opposite extreme is the coarse, or coarsest, or anti-discrete topology on S, in which the only open (and closed) subsets are S and the empty set.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are working in the Sorgenfrey plane, which is the product of $\mathbb{R}$ in the Sorgenfrey topology (a.k.a. the lower limit topology) with itself.

Then indeed $A = \{(x,-x): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ (mind the notation, yours is wrong) has the discrete topology, which means that *every* subset of $A$ is open (and closed) in the subspace topology that $A$ gets as a subspace of the Sorgenfrey plane. This holds because every singleton subset of $A$ is open by

$$\{(p,-p)\} = ([p,p+1) \times [-p, -p+1)) \cap A$$

where the product set is open by definition in the product of the Sorgenfrey lines, so the singleton set is open in the subspace topology on $A$.

As all subsets of $A$ are open (as unions of singleton sets!), all subsets of $A$ are closed (in the subspace topology on $A$) too (as the complement is also open), so the only dense subset of $A$ (a set whose closure equals $A$) is $A$ itself (every set equals its closure).

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the normal Sorgenfrey line, and $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the Sorgenfrey plane. But as you see from this example, this does **not** mean that $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cap A$ is dense in $A$.